# Selenium get_html_source

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a Verizon wireless phone page using Selenium at the following address:

http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/store/controller?item=phoneFirst&action=viewPhoneOverviewByDevice&deviceType=Phones&sortOption=priceSort&lid=//global//phones+and+accessories//cell+phones

I get to the page and use `get_html_source` to save the page with no problems but when I go to view the page I saved all the data about the phones is missing. I can't seem to figure out why it did not save the whole page.

Thanks in advance for your help!

note: This is being done in python

Comment: (Disregarding the ethics of screenscraping) How do you know all the data is missing? Have you looked directly at the source, or did you just load it into a browser? Also when i followed that link you posted i got a query page asking my location, no phones on it - so is your script getting the same?

Comment: I get the same page as slugster asking for my location. There's also the possibility that the page loads content in from another source and the HTML source doesn't contain the phone details. Depending on what you want to do, you could capture a screenshot of the page instead.

Answer (score 0):

I visit the URL you provided. I saw the source manually and using a web-driver; there is nothing you can get from the source.

Keep in mind that sometimes(maybe most of the times) all the data that you see in an HTML page can't be accessed using its source; because nowadays web designers use AJAX frequently and the source contains almost nothing; like this page that's full of JQuery and JS methods.

It's the code that I used, maybe it can help you in other cases:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/store/controller?&item=phoneFirst&action=viewPhoneOverviewByDevice&deviceType=Phones&sortOption=priceSort&lid=//global//phones+and+accessories//cell+phones"

browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source
print html_source
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead for printing it in screen try to capture it in a String and then store it in a notepad file. Since screen buffer have limited size it doesn't show all the page source content some times.